# understanding node.js error message

Tags: node.js

```
Error initializing middleware
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.cls_wrapMethod [as _load] node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:246:38)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> api/services/chargeService.js:3:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Function.cls_wrapMethod [as _load] node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:246:38)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Unexpected token ILLEGAL seems I made a typo or forgot to comment out a line in one of my source files. but the error message is very unhelpful.

is there any generic tools for parsing messages like this?

Comment: Check `api/services/chargeService.js:3:23` and `vm.js:53:16`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Thank you, the issue is solved for now but how did you do it?

Comment: posted answer, if something not clear, i will update answer

Answer (score 0):

This is callstack

```
Error initializing middleware                    <== graceful error message
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL            <== raw error message
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)    <== YOUR SCRIPT, CHECK HERE
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)        <== node script
    at Object.Module._extensions.js (module.js)  <== node script
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)            <== node script
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)  <== node script
    at Function.cls node_modules/.../shimmer.js) <== package script
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)         <== node script
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)        <== node script
    at Object.<anonymous> api/services/chargeService.js:3:23) <== YOUR SCRIPT, CHECK HERE
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)        <== node script, etc
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Function.cls_wrapMethod [as _load] node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:246:38)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Usually node scripts and npm packages don't throw unexpected exceptions, they have tests, so first of all you have to check your files

```
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
```

This means `exports.runInThisContext` function in file `vm.js` was executed previously exception catched

```
at Object.<anonymous> api/services/chargeService.js:3:23)
```

Same as above, object getter or setter was executed in file `chargeService` at line 3 column 23 before exception catched

Comment: [`vm.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/vm.js) is part of Node as well.

Comment: @robertklep might be, just tho about `exports.runInThisContext` of vm.js